git permission denied error in airflow dag when access git in subprocess or bashoperator
I'm using Airflow on my local env using Docker Compose The Docker compose I'm using is https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.9.0/docker-compose.yaml
Here are the docker compose ps
airflow-scheduler-1
airflow-triggerer-1
airflow-webserver-1
airflow-worker-1
postgres-1
redis-1

As part of of the task in Airflow DAG I need to execute git clone <repo> command either using subprocess or BashOperator however it fails with git permission denied error. Its able to execute ls and echo command but not git.
Note - Git is already installed on my system.
DAG code with subprocess
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import shlex
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

default_args = {
 'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1),
 'catchup': False
}

def _sub_process():
    cmd = ["ls"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    if p.returncode != 0:
      print(stderr)

with DAG('sub_processing', 
    schedule_interval='@hourly', 
    default_args=default_args) as dag:
    #Define tasks/operators

    sub = PythonOperator(
        task_id='sub',
        python_callable=_sub_process
    )

DAG code with BashOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import shlex
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

default_args = {
 'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1),
 'catchup': False
}

with DAG('sub_processing', 
    schedule_interval='@hourly', 
    default_args=default_args) as dag:

    run_this1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="run_after_loop1",
        bash_command='echo "hello world"'
    )


    run_this2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="run_after_loop2",
        bash_command="ls",
    )


    run_this3 = BashOperator(
        task_id="run_after_loop3",
        bash_command="git --version",
    )

    run_this1 >> run_this2 >> run_this3


I'm not sure why Airflow DAG task is not able to execute git command. Need help here

Do all workers have proper permissions to access git? There could be 1000 reasons for not being able to access a resource -not having permissions, request is not routable, IP/firewall etc. ls and echo are UNIX commands and will execute without needing to talk to git.

I'm using Docker Compose to run Airflow on my local. The Docker compose I'm using is https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.9.0/docker-compose.yaml

Would there be a possibility of BashOperator execute command inside airflow-worker-1 container where Git is not present

I think you are getting confused with airflow and git. These 2 are separate tools altogether. You might need to install git and setup permissions in your dockercompose if it is not included in the image you are pulling in. Yes, worker node need explicit access to git in this case

Yes. Correct. Worker node need explicit access to Git in my case

Yes. Correct. Worker node need explicit access to Git in my case

I executed Airflow Standalone server host the above DAG and its able to access the Git command now.
